# how to copy - paste xcode group copy iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

In iPhone Development, generally we use Xcode.

Now, we manage different groups within our project.

my Question is how do you copy the entire group (with including files in it) and paste within same project or other project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right/Ctrl click on the group you want to copy and select "Reveal in Finder." Select the files you want to import into the new project, and then just drag and drop into the new XCode project, being sure to select the "copy these files" check box that pops up. To import into the same project, you'll need to have different file names but you essentially follow the same process.

Comment: A group can include files from different folders.  So, choosing "Reveal in Finder" may not show all the files in the group, and may also reveal files which are not in the group.  This does not answer the question of how to copy an entire group to another project.

Answer (score 0):

kmit's answer is correct. Generally you should not make duplicate copies of the same source code files in the same project.  If you want to duplicate and change them, sure. But if you want to use the identical files in another target, just add the files to that target (select the group, Get Info, Targets tab, check the other target).  You can reuse the same source file  for building any number of applications in the same project.